# R- interpolar valores de columna

Tags: r, interpolacion

Estoy tratando de hacer la interpolación de la edad en el proyecto de kaggle del titanic.

El código que tengo planteado es:

```
titanic$age[is.na(titanic$age)] = approx(titanic$age, method = "linear")
```

Los valores que tengo de retorno son algo extraños

```
316 |Dean, Master. Bertram Vere | male | 1 | 3rd | S | England |2315 | 20.1106 | **1** | 2 | yes
317 |Dean, Miss. Elizabeth Gladys 'Millvina'| female | **0.1666666667** | 3rd | S | England | 2315 | 20.1106 | 1 | 2 | yes
```

Está hecho de forma correcta?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El resultado que muestras no es consistente con el código, por que de hecho, deberías estar teniendo algún tipo de error, por al menos dos razones: 1) `aprox()` retorna una lista de puntos y la asignación espera un vector y 2) Lo más probable que el resultado no sea del mismo tamaño de los puntos que quieres reemplazar, por que no estás indicando cuantos puntos quieres.

Ahora bien, `aporx()` con el método "linear" básicamente lo que hace es interpolar una serie de puntos entre dos puntos dados (x, y), básicamente ajustándolos a la recta que une estos puntos. No sé que tan bien está lo que te voy a sugerir, pero es ciertamente un mecanismo de imputación posible: la idea sería generar los puntos que caen en la recta que va desde la edad mínima a la máxima de la muestra, la cantidad de puntos sería el total de valores faltantes.

```
rango_edades <- data.frame(x=c(1, nrow(titanic)),
                           y=c(min(titanic$Age, na.rm = TRUE), 
                               max(titanic$Age, na.rm = TRUE))
)

edades_na <- approx(rango_edades$x, 
                    rango_edades$y, 
                    n=sum(is.na(titanic$Age)), 
                    method = "linear")$y

head(edades_na)

[1] 0.4200000 0.8721591 1.3243182 1.7764773 2.2286364
[6] 2.6807955

titanic$Age[is.na(titanic$Age)] = edades_na
```